# Function in jQuery activates too many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click

I am creating a game called Grape Clicker but when I try buying something called cotton candy grapes, the the function that I have set for click on an element activates a lot more than once.
My HTML is:

I have used the click method in jQuery and it has worked fine (only fired once per click), but now it is firing a few hundred times.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var score = 0;
  var ccg = 0;
  var emoji = String.fromCodePoint(0x0001F347);

  $("img").click(function() {
    score++;
    $("#span1").text(emoji + score + emoji);
    if (score >= 10 && score < 50) {
      $("#span1").css("color", "red");
    } else if (score >= 50 && score < 100) {
      $("#span1").css("color", "orange");
    } else if (score >= 100 && score < 500) {
      $("#span1").css("color", "yellow");
    } else if (score >= 500 && score < 1000) {
      $("#span1").css("color", "green");
    } else if (score >= 1000 && score < 5000) {
      $("#span1").css("color", "lime");
    } else if (score >= 5000 && score < 10000) {
      $("#span1").css("color", "blue");
    } else if (score >= 10000) {
      $("#span1").css("color", "purple");
    }

    if (score == 10) {
      alert("Achivement: 10");
    } else if (score == 50) {
      alert("Achivement: 50");
    } else if (score == 100) {
      alert("Achivement: 100");
    } else if (score == 500) {
      alert("Achivement: 500");
    } else if (score == 1000) {
      alert("Achivement: 1,000");
    } else if (score == 5000) {
      alert("Achivement: 5,000");
    } else if (score == 10000) {
      alert("Achivement: 10,000");
    }

    //PROBLEM
    $("#ccgS").click(function() {
      if (score > 10) {
        ccg++;
        score -= 10;
        $("#ccgNum").text(emoji + ccg + emoji);
        $("#span1").text(emoji + score + emoji);
      } else {
        alert("NOT ENOGUH GRAPES");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#span2 {
  color: purple;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="text"><span id="span1">Click the grapes!</span><span id="span2"><span id="ccgS">Cotton Candy Grapes</span><br><span id="ccgNum">0</span></span>
</h1>
<img src="images/grapes.png" height="25%" width="25%">
<p>0-9 - black<br>10-49 - red<br>50-99 - orange<br>100-499 - yellow<br>500-999 - green<br>1,000-4,999 - lime<br>5,000-9,999 - blue<br>10,000+ - purple<br>To buy a cotton candy grape press "Cotton Candy Grapes".<br>Cotton candy grapes cost 10 grapes<br>If
  you reload the page you lose all progress.</p>
```

I want it to be that when the user clicks the element with an ID of "ccgS", the function will fire once, not a thousand times.

Comment: It's because you're nesting the click event handlers. Every time the outer one fires you add another to `#ccgS`. To fix this, just move the inner handler outside of the first.

Comment: Looks like you're setting up the "click" handler for `"#ccgS"` *inside* the other "click" handler. Every call to jQuery `.click()` *adds* another handler without removing previously-added handlers. After a while, therefore, there'll be lots of redundant ones.

Comment: Also note that your second set of `if` conditions are redundant; just use `alert("Achivement: " + score)`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Looks like the OP wants the commas, so it would be `alert("Achievement: " + score.toLocaleString())`, with a spelling change too :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is ***very simple***. You placed the `//PROBLEM`matic code to the `onclick` event listener.

So, as many times you click the grape image, as many event listeners are added to `#ccgS` element, and as many dialog boxes appear on click.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var score = 0;
  var ccg = 0;
  var emoji = String.fromCodePoint(0x0001F347);

  $("img").click(function() {
    score++;
    $("#span1").text(emoji + score + emoji);
    if (score >= 10 && score < 50) {
      $("#span1").css("color", "red");
    } else if (score >= 50 && score < 100) {
      $("#span1").css("color", "orange");
    } else if (score >= 100 && score < 500) {
      $("#span1").css("color", "yellow");
    } else if (score >= 500 && score < 1000) {
      $("#span1").css("color", "green");
    } else if (score >= 1000 && score < 5000) {
      $("#span1").css("color", "lime");
    } else if (score >= 5000 && score < 10000) {
      $("#span1").css("color", "blue");
    } else if (score >= 10000) {
      $("#span1").css("color", "purple");
    }

    if (score == 10) {
      alert("Achivement: 10");
    } else if (score == 50) {
      alert("Achivement: 50");
    } else if (score == 100) {
      alert("Achivement: 100");
    } else if (score == 500) {
      alert("Achivement: 500");
    } else if (score == 1000) {
      alert("Achivement: 1,000");
    } else if (score == 5000) {
      alert("Achivement: 5,000");
    } else if (score == 10000) {
      alert("Achivement: 10,000");
    }
  });
  
    //PROBLEM
    $("#ccgS").click(function() {
      if (score >= 10) {
        ccg++;
        score -= 10;
        $("#ccgNum").text(emoji + ccg + emoji);
        $("#span1").text(emoji + score + emoji);
      } else {
        alert("NOT ENOGUH GRAPES");
      }
    });
});
```

```css
#span2 {
  color: purple;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="text"><span id="span1">Click the grapes!</span><span id="span2"><span id="ccgS">Cotton Candy Grapes</span><br><span id="ccgNum">0</span></span>
</h1>
<img src="images/grapes.png" height="25%" width="25%">
<p>0-9 - black<br>10-49 - red<br>50-99 - orange<br>100-499 - yellow<br>500-999 - green<br>1,000-4,999 - lime<br>5,000-9,999 - blue<br>10,000+ - purple<br>To buy a cotton candy grape press "Cotton Candy Grapes".<br>Cotton candy grapes cost 10 grapes<br>If
  you reload the page you lose all progress.</p>
```

Comment: So you did not explain the fix or what the issue was